When can I commute the 4-gradient and the "space-time" integral?
Let's say I have the following situation
$$I = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\int e^{k_{\mu}x^{\mu}} \;d^4k$$
Would I be able to commute the integral and the partial derivative? If so, why is that? In the same line of thought, in the situation I'm able to commute, would the result of this be
$$I = \int k_{\alpha}e^{k_{\mu}x^{\mu}}\;d^4k$$
Thanks in advance!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule
